# Sharepoint - download a specific file via rest api

Tags: rest, sharepoint, download, onedrive

How can I download a specific file from Sharepoint via rest api if i know only its url?

I also have credentials that allow me to login and manually download the file with "save as" from the browser.

URL Example:
https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/:x:/s/SUPPORT/Eb_tO10sutpEi-6iaRP1uWcBuNCjsOW2vQv569XQQPo8Gg

Comment: Maybe you can try to use [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) in order to achieve the request from the given url and credentials.

Comment: yeah, i know postman as a tool, but sharepoint api are not so clear in order to retrieve a file from its urls/id.

Comment: The Microsoft Graph Explorer is a great tool for learning an API. Once you know the URL and how to create credentials, any language supports downloading from a URL. https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

Answer (score 1):

A suggestion would be to use [Postman](https://www.postman.com/), as I have mentioned in the comments. There is a search button, where you can type the collection you need. For example `download file from sharepoint`. Give it a try, and hope this helps you.

[image]

Comment: Collections are different per computer.  Your search results are unique to your computer.

Comment: @johnk You can search and use other users' collections. I suggest you to try it :D